# prevent users from seeing application data

Tags: c#, xml

i have an desktop application in **c#** for reminding me english words that i submitted there ( it's for learning english language ) , all the data of the app go's into some **XML files** instead of databases like mysql or sqlserver or . . . 
now everything is Ok but i don't know how to prevent users of this app from seeing this data directly by opening files or removing the data when using the app , because i'm putting these files simply in executable file folder of the app and also i don't want to put these data in Windows Drive in order to prevent the files from being removed when OS is changed or removed .
any help will be appriciate

Comment: You could hash the values and decrypt them within your application after you've read them.  Users would still be able to open the XML files and see the structure, though; they just wouldn't be able to understand what the values were.

Comment: but i want to prevent users from seeing these files and from removing them also

Comment: Well, then, that's not possible.

Comment: @ako: The system is owned and run by the user, not by your application. You can obfuscate, but you cannot prevent the owner of a system from determining everything that is on it.

Comment: Hash is one way.  you would need to use an encryption process.  You can't really hide anything from someones computer.  You can make it difficult but not impossible.  (the more difficult you make it also makes it more difficult for you to program.)  The best wayt to make sure people cant mess with this would be to encrypt the entire file and store it in the application data folder.  Best you can do to prevent delete is to open and lock the file the entire time your app is running but you can't stop it entirely.

Comment: but these data is important for the application so the app must prevent users from modify it

Comment: @ako It's impossible to prevent a user from removing a file on *their* machine. Would you be happy if a program could dump files to your harddrive and have no way to remove them?

Answer (score 5):

There are two options available (Both options does not prevent the user to open the xml file):

1) You can encrypt the whole xml so it will be unreadable for user.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb7w85t6(v=vs.100).aspx

2) you can save your xml file in other formats like .sys or .fil . So user will not pay attention to your .xml file and your xml file will not open directly to default xml program.

It is a good idea to encrypt the whole xml data and then save it with other extension.
But user can still open it..!

Thanks

Comment: You could also use the .NET compress feature on the file. Either encryption or compression would turn it into an unreadable binary file. The encryption mainly just makes it so the user can't run a program to easily open the file.